# Display login form if user session timeout

Tags: javascript, ajax, primefaces

I'm making a project in primefaces and I'm puzzling in something simple.

The objective is:

When an AjAX request is made, send something to the browser so that it knows the session has expired.

By knowing that the session has expired, it knows it must display the login form (the contents are inside a `<template>` tag) in a popin (modal(?) box) and it displays it.

When the user tries to submit the form, the js intercepts the submit event and it sends the login using AJAX.

On successful login, re-send the previous AJAX request that had failed due to session timeout.

**Update:**
To solve this, I decided to use, a filter, I was able to do the request interception and I was able to analyze if the session had timed out. Given that, there seem to be a specific header that is always sent when it is a request using DOM's XMLHttpRequest(), so I can use that to decide the kind of answer it should give for session timeout.
With that, I send the answer to the client... Now what?

This is something super simple I had already made when not using any framework at all but now, using primefaces, I can't seem to be able to even get started, I have no clue how to do it.

This is on primefaces 5.0 with only its dependencies.

Comment: Try to use http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/exceptionHandler.xhtml with type="javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException"

Comment: @0x5a4d I didn't understand how that helps

Comment: if user does something when session is timed out (send ajax request), then ViewExpiredException will be raised, and p:ajaxExceptionHandler type="javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException" catched this exception. Inside attribute onexception you can execute javascript (redirect to login page) or envelop with p:ajaxExceptionHandler custom login form

Comment: @0x5a4d How do I resend the failed AJAX request afterwards?

Comment: If the user has performed 25 operations, and then disappeared, and after a while the session expires and the user is returned and sent the Ajax request, the exception occurred. Resends the failed request without performing the previous 25 user operations makes no sense, as you actually need to simulate them all. Simply informs the user that the session has expired and redirect.

Comment: @0x5a4d The user will %"#$&#&%# with the system. Besides, there was no server communication during those 25 operations. Not only that, I have already done something exactly like this with PHP on the server. It shouldn't be that hard!